# Centering Footer Content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble centering vertically the contents of my footer in the footer tag. I've tried setting the footer content `margin-top`. Display, Position the issue persists. I'm not sure what I've been doing wrong. If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

[Example of Issue on my Index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMH2U.png)

[*Update* what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FiIU.png)

```css
footer {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #1F1E1E; 
    height: 50%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.footercontent {
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.footerlogo {
    font-size: 15px;
}

.footerlogo img{
    height: 70px;
}

footer img{
    height: 60px;
}

footer a {
    color: white;
}

footer a:hover {
    color: #8FBAFF;
}

footer ul {
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
}


.caption {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.space {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.bold {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="footercontent">

    <div class="footerlogo col-md-3 footernone">
      <img src="img/motivel.png">
    <div class="space">
      <p><a href="">phone#</a></p>
      <p><a href="">emailadress</a> </p>
    </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-md-2 footerm">
        <ul class="bold">Explore</ul>
        <ul><a>Home</a></ul>
        <ul><a>About</a></ul>
        <ul><a>Services</a></ul>
        <ul><a>Contact</a></ul>
    </div>

<!--
    <div class="col-md-2 footernone">
        <ul class="bold">Follow</ul>
        <ul><a>Facebook</a></ul>
        <ul><a>Instagram</a></ul>
        <ul><a>Twitter</a></ul>
        <ul><a>Behance</a></ul>
    </div>
-->
    <div class="col-md-2 footernone">
        <ul class="bold">Legal</ul>
        <ul><a>Terms</a></ul>
        <ul><a>Privacy</a></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: `text-align: center`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add one more thing. I want the content to be vertically centered.

Comment: Well you have vertical-align set already

Comment: Yes, but it's not working.

Comment: Did you try text-align: center in the footer css

Comment: Yes, still not working. I'm thinking maybe there's code interfering but I've been messing around with it and still haven't found a fix.

Comment: When you run the code snippet it appears that it is centered vertically. Can you explain how you want the product to be different from what is shown after running the snippet in Stack Overflow?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap as a framework. The main code I'm running to structure the page is html, body {
height:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

Comment: Tim's answer seems fine if what you actually want is them all to be vertically centred, if that's not what you mean then perhaps an edited image of the correct alignment might help us figure out what needs to be done.

Comment: I've updated my question with a link to what I'd like done. Yes, I thought that what he had posted would be the solution. In my complete webpage, I have successfully vertically centered my content. Unfortunately, my footer is not responding properly. I'm starting to think that there's some interference in code that is affecting it, although I'm not certain.

Comment: Is this the issue you need solving? https://i.imgur.com/xE7xm6p.png

Otherwise we're going to need the context of the page its on in order to figure out clashing style issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you mean. But if you want to center the items to be vertically centered you can change `align-items: flex-start` to `align-items: center` in the .footercontent